# In the twin paradox, are some events lost to the observer turning around?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

From what I understand of the twin paradox, the time difference in time can be accounted for when the twin on a rocket ship turns around/switches reference frames.

Does that imply that, events that have occurred in this gap will be lost to the "younger twin"?

Can this be extended to such extreme as the following scenario?
The stationary twin fires a laser at the traveling twin capable of obliterating him. But the moving twin turn around at the right moment and "misses" that event entirely?

Comment: Look at the spacetime diagrams:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox  There are no gaps.

Comment: If the laser misses him, he's not obliterated.  If it hits him, he is.  If that answers your question, I'm not sure why you had to ask.  If it doesn't, I can't figure out what your question is.

Comment: @WillO sounds like the question is: Does the travelling twin experience a discontinuity in time, e.g. go directly from t = 30 seconds to t = 32 seconds (in some frame), and thus miss events at or around t = 31 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, relativity deals only with what *coordinates* different observers assign to events (where an event is a point in four-dimensional spacetime). Observers disagree as to what time or place something happened, but they all agree fundamentally on what happened. If someone in one frame of reference sees a spaceship being hit by a laser, then people in other frames of references may disagree as to when it happened, or whether it happened before or after other events, but they will all agree on whether it hit the spaceship, whether it destroyed the spaceship, etc.

As an analogy, the Gregorian calendar was introduced in 1582. The previous calendar, the Julian calendar, had been "losing" days at a rate of close to one per century. Since it had been in place for over a thousand years, it was off by several days. So the date had to "jump ahead" several days. Does that mean that there was a period of several days in which you could shoot someone, and they could "miss" the bullet because the day was skipped? Of course not. All that changed was what date was assigned to what day. It didn't change what actually physically happened.

If someone on a spaceship is first going away from Earth, and then turns around and comes back to the Earth, then the co-moving reference frame for the first part of their journey will be different from that of the return trip. So if they want to have a co-moving coordinate system in both parts, they're going to have to switch co-ordinate systems. Since the acceleration from going away to going back is when their velocity changes, and thus when they have to change their co-ordinate system if they want to keep it co-moving (and is the point that introduces an asymmetry between the person on the spaceship and a person on Earth, and therefore resolves the paradox of why the two have different elapsed time), this is a natural time in which to consider the "time difference" to happen, but since the amount of time difference depends on the length of the trip, there are also reasons to consider the time difference to accrue throughout the trip.

If at the turn-around point, the people on the spaceship "synch up" with Earth, they're going to have to move their calendar ahead. Since they can't change their velocity instantaneously, if they continuously adjust their calendar then they won't skip any dates, they'll just move through those dates very quickly. But if they adjust their calendar just once, after the acceleration is done, then there will be dates they skip. But there's an important distinction here: there are *dates* that they skip, but there aren't any *days* that they skip. A date is simply a label given to a particular day. Some of those labels will not have any days they are assigned to, and therefore be skipped. The people on the spaceship don't skip any *actual time*, they just skip ahead *in their labeling*. So, for instance, they might label one day Sep 30, and the next day Nov 1. There is a month of dates that aren't used, but there isn't an actual month of *time* that the people "jump over", any more than we jump ahead an hour in *actual time* for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the ship does not affect proper time inside the ship very much, and it certainly does not affect the final proper time that has passed for the stationary twin when they meet. It does affect the time and space coordinates for distant events, but the events themselves are the same. It's similar to seeing the 3D coordinates for a distant object change when you rotate a 3D frame. The object is still the same.

If turning the ship was the reason why the twin on the ship ages slower, then it shouldn't matter what distance the ship travels before turning. But that's not the case: if the ship travels twice as far before turning, the time difference will be twice as large (assuming everything else equal).

However, turning the ship has an important effect: it is what enables a non-straight path between the departure and arrival events, and this is what makes the elapsed proper time shorter on the ship. In the Minkowski metric the longest elapsed time for a worldline that connects two events is for a straight worldline, i.e. an inertial reference frame. For all other worldlines the elapsed time is *shorter*.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not.  Here's a simple geometrical/visual argument why.

First of all we can work in one spatial dimension safely.  Secondly we can also safely assume that only one twin undergoes acceleration.  (If I was being proper I'd need to justify both of these claims).  Finally the twins must meet twice at distinct events.  Oh, and spacetime is flat: all of this takes place in Minkowski spacetime.

So, pick the rest frame of the unaccelerated twin, which is inertial.  The world line of the other twin is some timelike curve which intersects the time axis of this frame (ie the world-line of the unaccelerated twin) twice.  This curve can only ever be a finite distance away from the time axis, so there are two timelike geodesics, parallel to the time axis (ie they are the worldlines of objects which are stationary with respect to the unaccelerated twin) which are bounds on the position of the accelerated twin: it never crosses them.

But any null geodesic which crosses one of them must cross the other.  Thus any null geodesic which crosses either of them must also intersect the worldline of the accelerated twin since it is trapped between them.  And all null geodesics intersect these lines.

(The trick you need to do in more than one spatial dimension is to think in terms of surfaces rather than lines.  But nothing changes.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it another way.  Imagine a very long train parked on the tracks. In each car there is a clock. At the train tracks there is also a clock positioned next to each train clock and the all these clocks are synchronized. The train accelerates and then reaches a high velocity and maintain that velocity. During the time that it maintain that velocity, it keeps track of the time in which it maintains that velocity, and then the train slows down and stops.

During this time of constant velocity, from the trains point of view, the track clocks had slowed down. During this time of constant velocity, from the train tracks point of view, the train clocks had slowed down.

But once the train had stopped, they could compare measurements of how long the train had maintained constant velocity.

The funny thing is, that either view could be in the right.

Lets say that the train and the tracks had been accelerated close to the speed of light off to the left, but when the train had accelerated off to the right in turn it was actually reducing its speed relative to the speed of light, thus the result would be that the clocks on the track would have measured a shorter time.

Confused ?